# Battery/Power indicator has a very low respond to plugging or unplugging charger ?

Tags: power-management, indicator

The top bar Power indicator has a very slow respond to plugging or unplugging the charger , I think it waits till percentage change .

if its unplugged and then plugged it wouldn't respond until the percentage change form x to x + 1 e.g ( from 25 to 26 )

I have tried to reinstall `gnome-power-management` but issue still persist.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 .

Comment: I have the same issues - I hope someone can find a resolution for this.